# Annotate data points for each column on multi-line plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, line-plot

I have a dataframe with multiple columns (columns represent months) and each row is a group, e.g.

```
    OCT20  NOV20  DEC20  JAN21
A   20     24     19     18
B   45     29     33     46
C   19     11     13     11
```

(This is just dummy data to get a reproducible solution).

I am plotting a line plot of this dataframe, with the columns as x-ticks and each row in the index as a line in the plot, and the values for each month per row are the y values.

Below is the code I use for plotting, which works fine. However, I want to annotate each datapoint with its value from the dataframe, but with the code below I get all the datapoints in one place.

```
%matplotlib inline

labels = ['OCT20', 'NOV20', 'DEC20', 'JAN21', 'FEB21', 'MAR21']

ax = df.T.plot(grid = True, figsize=(20,15), marker='o')

for col in df.columns:
    for id, val in enumerate(df[col]):
        ax.text(id, val, str(val))

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation=45)
    
plt.show()
```

And the output is this:
[image]

But I want each datapoint to correspond to the correct marker in the plot.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close! You've transposed the DataFrame, but then try to apply the text via the un-transposed DataFrame `df`:

```
plot_df = df.T  # Save the Transposition
ax = plot_df.plot(grid=True, figsize=(20, 15), marker='o')

for col in plot_df.columns:  # Use the Transposition
    for idx, val in enumerate(plot_df[col]):
        ax.text(idx, val, str(val))

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
labels = ['OCT20', 'NOV20', 'DEC20', 'JAN21']
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation=45)
```

[image: plot]

---

DataFrame used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'OCT20': {'A': 20, 'B': 45, 'C': 19},
    'NOV20': {'A': 24, 'B': 29, 'C': 11},
    'DEC20': {'A': 19, 'B': 33, 'C': 13},
    'JAN21': {'A': 18, 'B': 46, 'C': 11}
})
```

Comment: Aaah indeed, it was such a small detail I overlooked. Thanks, it worked great!